# Divs appearing outside of parent divs

Tags: css, html

I've looked at the similar questions on this issue, but none of them seem to actually address the issue that I'm having. Right now I'm just trying to display a stylized list and have far more trouble than I feel I should be.

There's a fiddle up [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZffFv/9). Basically I just want the test snippet to show up next to the image.

This is the actual template html that's being used (Mako):

```
% for datum in data.entries:
    <a href="#">
        <div class="result-container">
            <div class="result-header">
                <h1 class="result-title">${datum.data['display_name']}</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="result-body">
                <div class="thumbnail-wrapper">
                    <div class="result-thumbnail">
                        <img class="thumbnail" src="${datum.thumbnail}" alt="${datum.data['display_name']}"></img>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="result-snippets">
                    <div class="snippet">
                    ${datum.snippets}
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
% endfor
```

EDIT:

I realized I didn't make this clear enough so I updated the fiddle and made some comment, but please note that each of these elements is in a `LIST` That is that the same thing will appear multiple times going down the page. I'm looking for something that will work, not just once, but for every list item.

How do I get the snippet to show up to the right of the image. Or even better, why is it like that in the first place?

Comment: There's a variety of solutions, but this markup / template has a bit of "div-itis" (extra divs, potentially), which are making it more difficult to solve cleanly.  Basically, the div of the thumbnail-wrapper is full-width, which causes the result-snippets div to be **below** it.  A cleaner solution might be to pull those extra divs out.  If that's not possible, then some strategic css will work, although none of the proposed answers so far are very clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
 .thumbnail-wrapper {
        /*    width: 285px;
    */
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

**Update:**
With your updated fiddle
Change it to

```
.result-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
        clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you need

http://jsfiddle.net/ZffFv/8/

```
 .result-snippets {
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left:300px;
}
```

Comment: Not a list in the text, I mean multiple full elements. Check out the updated fiddle.

Comment: Oh yes, exactly. Sorry, you were a little behind Octane though.

Comment: No worries s/he got better coding resolution

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking to do?  I have the snippet floating next to the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZffFv/2/

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
     <div class="result-container">
          <div class="result-header">
               <h1 class="result-title">Test Title</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="result-body">
               <div class="thumbnail-wrapper">
                    <div class="result-thumbnail">
                     <img class="thumbnail" src="http://www.anirudh.net/courses/cse585/project1/results/orig/lenna.gif" alt="${datum.data['display_name']}"></img>
                </div>
                    <div class="result-snippets">
                     <div class="snippet">
                     This is a test snippet
                      </div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
     </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.result-header {
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: normal;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.result-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.snippet {
    color: #666666;
    font-family:"Open Sans", "Arial";
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.thumbnail-wrapper {
    /*    width: 285px;
*/
    overflow:hidden;
}
.result-thumbnail {
    width: 300px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    float: left;
}
.result-snippets {
    float: right;
}
.result-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.page-number {
    width: 30px;
}
.search-icon {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: First I included your result-snippets div and its nested divs inside the thumbnail-wrapper div, then I needed to float your ".result-thumbnail" class to the left and float your ".result-snippets" class to the right.  The floats allow the elements to sit next to eachother nicely like in the fiddle.

Comment: Ah sorry, but I checked it out and that totally blows up for multiple items in a list.